# bash script to rename database with current timestamp

Tags: mysql

I want to have a bash script that renames a MySQL database with a timestamp suffix.

```
DB=database
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)

(
  echo "CREATE DATABASE $DB_$DATE;"

  echo "USE $DB;"

  echo 'SHOW TABLES;' | while read TABLE; do
    echo "RENAME TABLE $DB.$TABLE TO $DB_$DATE.$TABLE;"
  done

) | mysql ${DB} -N

exit 0;
```

Error:

`'RENAME TABLE database.SHOW TABLES; TO database_20191205_121556.SHOW TABLES;;'`

`ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLES' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'SHOW TABLES;' | while read TABLE; do
```

This doesn't loop over the list the tables, this just loops over the single string "SHOW TABLES".

You probably want:

```
mysql ${DB} -Nse "SHOW TABLES" | while read TABLE; do
```

---

Re your comment:

Consider the following two commands:

```
ls | while read filename ; do echo $filename ; done

echo ls | while read filename ; do echo $filename ; done
```

Try these two commands. Not in a script, just in your shell. What is the output?

Merely *echoing* a string containing a command does not run that command.

Merely reading a string into a variable you name `$TABLE` does not mean it contains a table name.

---

Okay I am trying your script but piping to `cat` instead of to `mysql`:

```
DB=database
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)

(
  echo "CREATE DATABASE $DB_$DATE;"

  echo "USE $DB;"

  echo 'SHOW TABLES;' | while read TABLE; do
    echo "RENAME TABLE $DB.$TABLE TO $DB_$DATE.$TABLE;"
  done

) | cat

exit 0;
```

Just so we can see the output:

```
CREATE DATABASE 20191205_174532;
USE database;
RENAME TABLE database.SHOW TABLES; TO 20191205_174532.SHOW TABLES;;
```

The first two echo statements output legal SQL statements for `CREATE` and `USE`. That's fine.

But the `while` loop is not reading table names, it's reading one string: "SHOW TABLES" and assuming it is a table name. But it's not a table name, it's just a string that happens to be literally "SHOW TABLES". It is not the output of *running* "SHOW TABLES", it's just the string itself.

I'm not sure how else to explain this.

---

Oh, a second problem that has nothing to do with the loop.

In shell, `_` is a valid character in a variable name. So `$DB` is different from `$DB_`. You should delimit variable names if you use them in a string with a `_` character following.

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE ${DB}_${DATE};"
```

The way you wrote it, it tries to substitute the value of `$DB_` which is a non-existent variable.

Comment: All of the preceding commands work correctly. Why does that specific command need to be run with the client when it's already pipped onto the block? Thx

Comment: re your edit, I understand when we're running from bash so I guess my question is why do the `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` work? Is it because we're not using their output? The `echo`, in those instances, run the commands into the already initialized mysql client prompt (not bash).

Comment: I get it, I just figured it would run the cmds, like the others, but the output is then piped to `while read`. Thanks

Comment: With all due respect, I really can't understand how you would think that would happen. You `echo` a string, and pipe that into `while read`. There is no way MySQL comes into that pipeline.

Comment: Because I thought the `echo` in this instance was into the mysql client. The `echo` of `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` actually run the commands. I figured `echo SHOW TABLES;` would run `SHOW TABLES;` into the mysql client.